# asp.net project fail redirect to my login page using IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

In my visual studio when I run my project it will go to Login.aspx, when I use IIS to browse my project it cannot go to Login.aspx.

I had set the default document to : Login.aspx already in my IIS.
I tried to clear all cache but still its not working. It keeps open page call "Bootstrap 3 Admin".

Comment: very wrong to set as default page the login.aspx. You can define that on web.config as the page that the user go if its no logged in. Please find a tutorial to see how all that is setup.

Answer (score 0):

there's a index.htm file inside my project ,just delete it.the index generated when i build my project